# scp backup command with automated folder is not overwriting older files when executed twice

Tags: ssh, backup, scp, web

I want to do a backup from my website. I am using following command, to have automated a directory with the correct dat:

```
scp -rp abc@ssh.web1.rz.xyz.de:webdir/ /mnt/Webseite/Backups/"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
```

This works perfectly. But if I execute the same command a second time on the same day, it will copy the directory "webdir" into the Date-Folder.

Executing first time:

```
/mnt/Website/Backups/2020-05-22/"files"
```

Executing second time:

```
/mnt/Website/Backups/2020-05-22/"files"
/mnt/Website/Backups/2020-05-22/webdir/"files"
```

But I want to have these "old" Backup from the same day overwritten. So that I have only one Backup for each day.

What am I doing wrong here? 
I guess it is very easy to solve... Google could not help me.

Comment: Topf, I saw you'd un-accepted my answer. That's fine - it's your acceptance - but I'd appreciate a comment explaining why it doesn't work for you. Perhaps I've misunderstood part of your requirements and a small fix will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the target directory, so that the topmost directory of the source isn't co-opted into creating it for you. The side-effect is that the `webdir` directory itself will be included in the backups tree - if that's a showstopper of a problem consider using `rsync` instead

```
dst="/mnt/Webseite/Backups/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
mkdir -p "$dst"
scp -rp abc@ssh.web1.rz.xyz.de:webdir/ "$dst"
```

You can see this at work with this example

```
# Set up the scenario on the remote source
mkdir -p /tmp/src/webdir
touch /tmp/src/webdir/{a,b,c}

# Copy the first time, and review the results
dst="/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
mkdir -p "$dst"
scp -rp remotehost:/tmp/src/webdir/ "$dst"

find "$dst" | sort

/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/a
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/b
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/c

# Change some files
touch /tmp/src/webdir/{d,e}

# Copy the second time, and review the results
scp -rp remotehost:/tmp/src/webdir/ "$dst"

find "$dst" | sort

/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/a
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/b
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/c
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/d
/tmp/dst/webseite/backups/2020-05-23/webdir/e
```

Finally, if you really don't want to have `website` in the backups (destination) directory tree, use `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -a remotehost:/tmp/src/webdir/ "$dst"
```

Comment: Apologies for disagreeing, but I reckon this has the same behaviour as the command in the initial question. I tested it (albeit with a local source and remote destination) and yeah, first time it works fine (inc hidden files), 2nd time it clones the webdir directory into $dst.

Comment: @Pedro with a remote src and local dst I reckoned it worked just fine for me

Comment: I've repeated the test exactly in these conditions and I'm afraid I got the opposite result. So your answer is incorrect against what the original question referred to.
`$ scp -rp user@remote:test/ ${HOME}/newdir
...
$ scp -rp user@remote:test/ ${HOME}/newdir
...
$ tree -a newdir
newdir
├── a
├── b
├── .c
└── test
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── .c

1 directory, 6 files`

Comment: @Pedro please see the worked example

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests and worked out my previous answer was incorrect. I've since found that actually it's preferable that the directory doesn't exist on the destination. It's expected that the folder ends up inside the DATE one the 2nd time you run the command, since the first time the copy occurs as if the source directory was renamed (since the destination doesn't exist). The 2nd time it exists and scp works out that you want to clone the directory into the existing one.

Solution for your problem is to remove it first...

```
rm -rf /mnt/Webseite/Backups/"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" #or move it if you want to keep the files
scp -rp abc@ssh.web1.rz.xyz.de:webdir /mnt/Webseite/Backups/"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
```